# How to ask webcam to auto focus with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality

Currently, I am working on some Augmented Reality mobile app with Unity3D. The performance is impacted by the image quality.

Is there some way to ask  webcam to auto focus with Unity3D?

Comment: Hi flyzhao, Have you successfully done this? Have you forced the webcam or device camera to focus from within Unity?

Comment: @Joshua I am not working on it now. But u can find some android native plugins from asset store. It may resolve this problem. Also, i think kao 's answer is well. It would be the best method, if you know some native knowledge about android.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know it is not possible in pure Unity3D.

However, if you are developing this on Android, you can write a plugin in java, which sets autofocus and call it from Unity3D.

```
public void enableAutofocus() {
    camera = camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

And then, you have to call your class from Unity3D:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject("com.mypackage.Autofocus");
        jo.Call("enableAutofocus");
    }
}
```

You can find more info about creating Java plugins for Unity3D [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html).

Comment: Hi Kao, Are you sure this is possible? Have you tried this yourself? Mine does not seem to be working...

Comment: Can you please help me re-write this snippet for the new `camera2`? I am really confused... I just need the `enableAutofocus` method to open the camera and set its focus. Thanks