# Android deprecated android.hardware.Camera and now recommend using android.hardware.camera2 but this is not available in anything below API 21

Tags: android, android-camera, deprecation-warning

I have an application that supports back to **Android API 19 (KitKat)** and there is **heavy Camera** use internally.

Currently, `android.hardware.camera2` is the recommended way of using the **camera API** and `android.hardware.Camera` is **deprecated**.

Is there a way to **support API 19** and stop using `android.hardware.Camera` without getting **deprecation warnings** in my build? If so, how?

The only other question I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065930/android-camera-android-hardware-camera-deprecated) but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you would use

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    //use old camera API
}else{
    //use new camera API
}
```

then you can support what you want

Comment: I was aware of this method but will this eliminate the build warnings I see from Lint in Gradle?

Comment: no it will not, nothing will if you want to support lower version, the only thing you can do it use `@SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )` to suppress it