# can anybody please tell me what is this error in android studio

Tags: android, android-camera, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I have

[image: Android Studio]

I am making an app about a simple test that tells the truth. I want to turn the led of the camera on/off. Can anybody tell me where is the error here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065930/android-camera-android-hardware-camera-deprecated

Comment: Also, you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: thank you , wich part you dont have understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, but a warning "Deprecated Class", this mean `Camera` class can be removed(not supported) from future versions of Android.

Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) link for new `Camera` apis.

According to the Java Documentation:

**Deprecated Class >>** *A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.*

To turn on FlashLight read this >> [Check and turn flashLight ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android/6069503#6069503)

Comment: but when i install in my device it does work i mean it not telling any error or something just is not turn on the led WHy ?

Comment: Its not error, LED doesn't turn ON automatically with camera api. You have to write code for that too

Comment: Can You Help with any examples please because im new in android Studio

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069503/519718