# Capturing an image without storing it to internal/external storage

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to transfer image to server captured via camera "without storing it into internal or external storage" due to security reasons. Please Help!

Comment: Share what you've tried so far.

Comment: Why dont you just store it, upload it, delete it?

Comment: Make it base64 string and send it, that way you don't need to store it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to connect the android app to a web service by storing it in memory in a Bitmap variable in memory and destroy it after the code is used or image is sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Camera#takePicture(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)) that will return the picture taken as a byte array through [PictureCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html).

Here is a pseudo code that takes a picture.

```
Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = () -> Log.i("Shutter has been triggered");
Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback = (data, camera) -> Log.d("Picture has been taken.");
Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = (data, camera) -> {
        // Do something with the picture here.
    };

Camera camera = Camera.open();
camera.startPreview();
camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback)
```

Please note that this sample uses the ["old" Camera V1 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), which is very different of [Camera V2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html). You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065930/android-camera-android-hardware-camera-deprecated) for a full diff of those 2 APIs